# Por que uma classe herdeira de outra resulta em "false" utilizando o instanceof?

Tags: javascript, herança, instanciar-objeto

Estudando sobre JavaScript pude perceber que ao herdar uma classe de outra com construtor Extends e compara-las utilizando o operador InstanceOf, resulta em false a não ser que você instâncie novamente utilizando o "new", alguém poderia me explicar esse conceito?

```
class Mamifero {
    constructor(especie, genero, patas) {
        this.especie = especie;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.patas = patas;
    };
};

class Lobo extends Mamifero {
    constructor(especie, genero, patas, raca, cor) {
        super(especie, genero, patas);
        this.raca = raca;
        this.cor = cor;
    };
};

let loboCinza = new Lobo("Canis Lupus", "Macho", 4, "Lobo Cinzento", "Cinza");

console.log(loboCinza);

console.log(Lobo instanceof Mamifero);
//output: false

console.log(new Lobo instanceof Mamifero);
//output: true
```

Achei que uma classe sendo herança de outra, o resultado do operador InstanceOf deveria retornar "true" ao compara-las.

Comment: Resumindo, `instanceof` mais ou menos compara se um objeto é uma instância de uma classe, no primeiro, você está verificando se a classe `Lobo` é um objeto criado a patir da classe `Mamifero` (ou outra que a extenda) e não é, `Lobo` é uma classe que extende `Mamifero`

Answer (score 4):

O primeiro você está perguntado se a **classe** `Lobo` é uma instância de `Mamifero`. Uma classe não é uma instância tradicional. Em JavaScript, uma linguagem orientada a objetos prototípica, tudo é instância, mas uma classe tem características especiais em relação ao objeto normal, por exemplo ela tem um construtor que a objeto instanciado dela não terá. Mas como todos os objetos ele herda de `Object`, como pode ver no exemplo abaixo.

Nem mesmo `Mamifero` é uma instância de `Mamifero`, porque é uma classe.

O segundo você instancia a classe `Lobo` e cria um novo objeto, ou seja, você cria uma instância. Não guarda em variável alguma, mas a instância é criada. Então já tem uma chance de ser verdadeiro. E aí analisamos que `Lobo` herda de `Mamifero`, então toda instância da primeira é também uma instância da segunda.

Lembre-se que há precedência entre operadores, então quando usa o `new Lobo` é como se estivesse usando `(new Lobo)`.

```js
class Mamifero {
    constructor(especie, genero, patas) {
        this.especie = especie;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.patas = patas;
    };
};

class Lobo extends Mamifero {
    constructor(especie, genero, patas, raca, cor) {
        super(especie, genero, patas);
        this.raca = raca;
        this.cor = cor;
    };
};
let loboCinza = new Lobo("Canis Lupus", "Macho", 4, "Lobo Cinzento", "Cinza");
console.log(loboCinza instanceof Mamifero);
let lobo = new Mamifero("Canis Lupus", "Macho", 4);
console.log(lobo instanceof Mamifero);
console.log(Lobo instanceof Mamifero);
console.log(Mamifero instanceof Mamifero);
console.log(new Lobo instanceof Mamifero);
console.log((new Lobo) instanceof Mamifero);
console.log((new Mamifero) instanceof Mamifero);
console.log(Lobo instanceof Object);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Operators/Instanceof.js).

Answer (score 4):

O operador `instanceof` é utilizado para verificar se um objeto pertence a uma determinada classe ou a uma classe que herda de outra. No entanto, ao utilizá-lo com as classes diretamente, como `Lobo instanceof Mamifero`, o resultado será `false`.

O motivo é que o operador `instanceof` verifica se o protótipo de um objeto é igual ao protótipo da classe especificada ou de uma classe derivada. No seu caso, a classe `Lobo` não é o protótipo da classe `Mamifero`. Ambas são classes independentes no sistema de classes JavaScript.

Quando você faz `new Lobo`, você está criando uma nova instância da classe `Lobo`, que herda de `Mamifero`. Portanto, a instância criada com `new Lobo` é de fato uma instância de `Lobo` e, por herança, uma instância de `Mamifero`.

No entanto, quando você compara a própria classe `Lobo` com `Mamifero` utilizando `Lobo instanceof Mamifero`, você está perguntando se a classe `Lobo` é uma instância da classe `Mamifero`, o que não é verdade.

Se você quiser verificar se uma instância de `Lobo` é uma instância de `Mamifero`, você pode fazer:

```js
console.log(loboCinza instanceof Mamifero); // true
```

Isso ocorre porque `loboCinza` é uma instância da classe `Lobo`, que herda de `Mamifero`, então também é uma instância de `Mamifero`.

Lembre-se de que o operador `instanceof` é usado para verificar instâncias de objetos, não as próprias classes. Se você quiser verificar se uma classe herda de outra, pode fazer algo como:

```js
console.log(Lobo.prototype instanceof Mamifero); // true
```